# How to modify the position of heads-up notification in systemui

Tags: android

The default heads-up notification is displayed in the center, but I want it to be displayed on the left. How to modify it, I can't find a valid place to modify it.Can you help me? thank you very much

Comment: What's 'heads-up notification' ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!The header notification is what this image shows. [link](https://miro.medium.com/max/750/1*w00Y5rN7Ih2ewd6MvqwHGg.png)

Comment: Try using a [Custom notification layout](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any way to achieve this requirement by modifying the systemUI.